# Hiding data field name in Visio Data Graphic Displayed as Text

Tags: visio

I am using Data Graphic to format my shapes. The data field that I am using to specify data graphics is 'name' and the formatting scheme (Displayed As) I am using is 'Text'. But when I do that, it not only shows value against the shapes but also field name i.e. 'name'. I don't want field name to appear, only values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data** -> **Advanced Data Graphics** -> **Available Data Graphics**
[image: Select your Data Graphics]

In **Edit Data Graphics** window select **Edit Item**
[image: Select Edit Item]

In **Edit Item** window select field **Label position** and change it value to **No show**[image: Change to "No show" state]

Sorry last screenshot with Russian interface :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- basically Label field has to be made blank , by default it is [Default].